# Unreadable .js file? How to convert back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 files something.js, something.min.js and something.style.js
The third is unreadable (here is in my server where I uploaded ): [Removed link for good reasons].
I want to convert back the file to normal, or visit as readable strings. And it will be good if I can convert my normal js to this format.
Thanks for any help and sorry for my grammatical errors :)

Comment: Threat detected by my AV.

Comment: jsbeautifier.org should do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a classic obfusquation error.

I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ and here you are !

http://pastebin.com/mH1x33Un